# google map on iphone exception

Tags: iphone, google-maps, ios5, google-maps-sdk-ios

i am trying to add a google map to my iphone application , i follow what google says here 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios

i did all what they said and unformatunately, i have six errors when building my application, those are :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_objc_setProperty_nonatomic", referenced from:
      -[GMSx_PBGeneratedMessage setExtensionRegistry:] in GoogleMaps(ProtocolBuffers.o)
  "_NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey", referenced from:
      _GMSSetSkipBackupAttribute in GoogleMaps(GMSUtils.o)
  "_objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy", referenced from:
      -[GMSBlockAnimationDelegate setStartBlock:] in GoogleMaps(GMSCoreAnimation.o)
      -[GMSBlockAnimationDelegate setCompletionBlock:] in GoogleMaps(GMSCoreAnimation.o)
      -[GMSGLTileProvider setAllTilesDeadBlock:] in GoogleMaps(GMSGLTileProvider.o)
      -[GMSUserEvent3Logger setOutputFilter:] in GoogleMaps(GMSUserEvent3Logger.o)
      -[GMSPanoramaLink setPanoramaID:] in GoogleMaps(GMSPanoramaLink.o)
      -[GMSIconCache setName:] in GoogleMaps(GMSIconCache.o)
  "_objc_setProperty_atomic", referenced from:
      -[GMSDASHProtobufferRequest setProtobuffer:] in GoogleMaps(GMSDASHConnectionRequest.o)
      -[GMSDASHConnection setServerURL:] in GoogleMaps(GMSDASHConnection.o)
      -[GMSVectorModifierMapTileService setTileFilter:] in GoogleMaps(GMSVectorModifierMapTileService.o)
      -[GMSx_GTMHTTPFetcher setMutableRequest:] in GoogleMaps(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
      -[GMSx_GTMHTTPFetcher setCredential:] in GoogleMaps(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
      -[GMSx_GTMHTTPFetcher setProxyCredential:] in GoogleMaps(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
      -[GMSx_GTMHTTPFetcher setPostData:] in GoogleMaps(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
      ...
  "_objc_setProperty_atomic_copy", referenced from:
      -[GMSDASHBlocksRequest setAsyncRequestFailedHandler:] in GoogleMaps(GMSDASHConnectionRequest.o)
      -[GMSDASHConnection setExperimentIDs:] in GoogleMaps(GMSDASHConnection.o)
      -[GMSx_GTMHTTPFetcher setServiceHost:] in GoogleMaps(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
      -[GMSx_GTMHTTPFetcher setDownloadPath:] in GoogleMaps(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
      -[GMSx_GTMHTTPFetcher setTemporaryDownloadPath:] in GoogleMaps(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
      -[GMSx_GTMHTTPFetcher setComment:] in GoogleMaps(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
      -[GMSx_GTMHTTPFetcher setLog:] in GoogleMaps(GTMHTTPFetcher.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIActivityViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleMaps(GMSServices.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**NOTE, my base sdk is ios 5 and my development target is 5**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version 1.5 of the SDK requires a minimum of iOS 6 - this might be why you are seeing those errors.

If you must support iOS 5, you could try downloading one of the older versions:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases

Comment: please which version should I use ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: I guess the latest version of 1.4 (so 1.4.3).

Comment: I tried 1.4.3 and i have an exception which is (error 400, the operation can't be completed), however i tried my application on a real machntoich and it works ,i dont' know why on vmware not working :( please help

Comment: Try Version 1.4.0, July 2013