# which google map version for ios 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, google-maps, ios5

I am using mac lion os 10.7.4, i want to integrate my application with google map. thus, i read the official google map guide, then i got this exception [google map on iphone exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222427/google-map-on-iphone-exception/19225204?noredirect=1#19225204) . as a result, i discoverd that i have to use another version of google map in order to support ios 5 , but unfortunately i am not able to know which version is.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

versions smaller than 1.5 supports iOS down to to 5.1 but they aren't that reliable i experienced.

---

with a not supported HACK you can support 5.0 :D but that is NOT a supported config:

```
#pragma mark - workaround
//make it work on 5.0 :D
NSString* const NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey = @"NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey";
```

Comment: i have hackntoc , mac on windows vmware, does that work ? also, why the code pleaase?

Comment: we ended up using mkmapview on ios5.x as they are google maps also

Comment: doesn't matter main.m or so. it makes gms think iOS 5.0 is 5.1

Comment: but again: unsupported

Comment: i don't care about support or not, i am just practicing so i would like to code a draft applicatoins just to teach myself

Comment: i accept ur applicatoin, i will download google mape 1.4, and then if i had problems, i would ask u kindly, thanks u very moch

Comment: i found version 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, which one is the right i have to know please?

Comment: I got this exception `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x988de90'
*** First throw call stack:
` hepl please